# Why is upsert adding multiple documents instead of one?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using `upsert` to update a document in `mongodb` if it exists and insert new if it doesn't. It's working fine, but whenever I update or insert, it saves multiple documents in the db. For example, if I want to update one field called `user_name` by adding its value as `Ammy`, then it saves one document with `user_name` as `A`, then with `user_name` as `m`, then again `m`, then finally with `user_name` as `Ammy`. Totally 4 separate documents for one entry. What is the issue?

Below is the code:
Main.js

```
  Router.route('/temp1/:ppid', function () {
  this.render('temp1', {
  data: function () {
  return Dbs.findOne({user_id:this.params.ppid});

  Router.go("/temp1",{},{user_id:this.params.ppid});
  }
  });
  });


   Template.temp1.events({
   'keyup .sub'(event)  {
   onst target= event.currentTarget;
   const user_id1 =target.user_id.value;
   const add =target.add.value;   
   const const = target.const.value;
   const path1 = target.path.value;
   const user_name1 =target.user_name.value;
   var p=Router.current().params.ppid;

    Meteor.call('dbs.update',p,user_id1, cont1, add1, 
    pth1,user_name1);

    }
    });
```

usermethod.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
 'dbs.updateuser'(p, user_id1, cont1, add1, pth1,user_name1) {
    Dbs.update({ user_id: p }, {
        $set: {
          user_id: user_id1,
          user_name:user_name1,
          cont: cont1,
          add: add1,
          pth: pth1
        }
      },
      { upsert: true }
      );
     }
     });
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Which basically says you are expected to show a "reproducible" case in order that we believe you. If you can show a way that reproduces what you claim, then someone can point out what needs to be done differently.

Comment: Your example code is different from what you're explaining.

Comment: No its correct .actually i missed user_name field while editing.

Comment: Can you show us where and how do you call this method ?

Comment: Also, why do you use both `p` and `user_id1` as `user_id`?

Comment: Odds are that you're calling this method in a helper on the client side and that it's running multiple times. Call it in an event handler instead.

Comment: I have added other code where i am calling the method @Gaëtan Rouziès.pls check what is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Styx mentioned in his comment, you are using the variable `p` AND `user_id1` as value for your field `user_id`. You will be able to do what you want, **only** if the variable `p` and `user_id1` **have the same value**.

Three solutions:

1. Don't change your update code, but be sure that `p` and `user_id1`
   have the same value
2. Change your update code, and only use the `user_id1` variable
3. Change your update code, and only use the `p` variable

Example with the second solution :

```
Meteor.methods({
'dbs.updateuser'(p, user_id1, cont1, add1, pth1,user_name1) {
    Dbs.update({ user_id: user_id1 }, // this value must be the same
    { 
      $set: {
            user_id: user_id1, // than this value, so it wont insert more documents
            user_name:user_name1,
            cont: cont1,
            add: add1,
            pth: pth1
      }
    },
    { upsert: true });
}
});
```

EDIT: 4th solution, remove simply the line with the `user_id` field in the `$set` tag.

```
Meteor.methods({
'dbs.updateuser'(p, user_id1, cont1, add1, pth1,user_name1) {
    Dbs.update({ user_id: p },
    { 
      $set: {
            user_name:user_name1,
            cont: cont1,
            add: add1,
            pth: pth1
      }
    },
    { upsert: true });
}
});
```

Comment: Value of p and user_id1  are same.but the issue is code adds multiple documents.@Gaëtan Rouziès

Comment: I understand your problem don't worry, but are you sure of that the two var have the EXACT same value ? It's useless to use two variable with the same value. You have to be really sure, please try using only one variable.

Comment: Yes i am sure that p and user_id1 have same values.Let me explain you what i  actually want to do.i have some user details in mongo db which i want to update so when i enter any value it saves multiple times.as i said earlier it saves seperate documents for each alphabet i enter

Comment: Is it the issue of "keyup" that i am using ?

Comment: The fact that you are using keyup just mean that the event will execute for every key that you type. But its ok, there is no problem with that. I edited my code with a 4th solution, can you try with this code ? If this doesn't work, show us more detailed about the documents inserted (show us all the field, not only the `user_name`).

Comment: Thanks @Gaëtan Rouziès. Its  working finally.I removed user_id:user_id1 from my code and its working perfect. Thank you so much for taking out your time to solve this issue.